# Issue with layout in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, layout

### This my first question in StackOverflow. Hope everyone can give me some ideas or solutions to solve my problems. All help is appreciated.

My question is:
I'm planning to create an app to listen to audio and then, try to answer the questions.
My problem is that I have a list audio and each audio has a bunch of questions.
When I select an audio, the layout will display like the picture attached. Moreover, Only has 3 answers for all questions.

How can I create radio button group and text view automatically for a package of questions for each audio selected in XML without repeating create a layout for each one?
I saved a package of questions for each audio in the database.

Thanks a lot.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yqKBd.png)

Comment: welcome to Stack Overflow.  You're generally going to get a much better response if you include what you have already tried.  Please see [How to Ask a Good Question](/help/how-to-ask) and [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

You can create the layouts and radio buttons dynamically using codes only without dofferent xml for each of them. Here is simple guide for you. Hope this answer your question.

http://www.mysamplecode.com/2011/10/android-programmatically-generate.html

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Godslave Asad. I will take a look at it now.